# Scrapy with selenium and chrome driver retain the session in multiple request

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy and Selenium with the chrome driver to scrape a website. I am not able to scrape the website using Scrapy only because there is some protection mechanism implemented in the website which is giving a 404. When I am using selenium with scrapy I am able to access the page html. But the problem is when I am using selenium I am not able to retain the session cookies on all the links accessed through scrapy. I want to set some session parameters like country, language etc.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
class SettingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'setting'
  allowed_domains = ['example.com']
  start_urls = ['http://example.com/']

  def __init__(self):
      self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

  def start_requests(self):
      url = 'http://www.example.com/'
      self.driver.get(response.url)
      yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

  def parse(self, response):
      csrf = response.xpath('//input[@name="CSRFToken"]/@value').extract_first().strip()
      print('------------->' + csrf)
      url = 'http://www.example.com/settings'

      form_data = {'shippingCountry': 'ARE', 'language': 'en', 'billingCurrency': 'USD', 'indicativeCurrency': '',
                 'CSRFToken:': csrf}
      yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=form_data, callback=self.after_post)

  def getShippingCountry(self, response):
      country = response.css("a#shipping-country::text").extract_first().strip()
      return country

  def after_post(self, response):
      country = self.getShippingCountry(response)
      print('------------->' + country)
```

Comment: Since you are using single chrome, the session will be maintained. That's not an issue, the issue may be the order of your commands

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cookie

```
cookie = {‘name’ : ‘foo’, ‘value’ : ‘bar’}
driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

and if you need to get your cookie you can use

```
driver.get_cookies()
```

For more information read [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html?highlight=cookie)